# With and Android System-Level app, how do you inject AXIS_RTRIGGER or AXIS_GAS events?

Tags: android, kotlin, input, android-source

I'm trying to make my own sort of controller that goes along with a system-level app that does have "android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" permission. The app runs in the background and interprets hardware buttons then uses InputManager to send them to the active display. This is on Android 12L minimum OS version with Kotlin. Looked at Github and cs.android.com and can't find anything similar except for unit tests on ca.android.com but they just verify that the axis values are converted to a string, not making it to an actual view.

I cannot figure out how to get this to work

```
        val eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        val pointerProperties = MotionEvent.PointerProperties()
        pointerProperties.id = 1
        val pointerCoords = MotionEvent.PointerCoords()
        pointerCoords.setAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_RTRIGGER, value)
        val event = MotionEvent.obtain(
            /* downTime= */ eventTime,
            /* eventTime= */ eventTime,
            /* action= */ MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,
            /* pointerCount= */ 1,
            /* pointerProperties= */ arrayOf(pointerProperties),
            /* pointerCoords= */ arrayOf(pointerCoords),
            /* metaState= */ 0,
            /* buttonstate= */ 0,
            /* xPrecision= */ 0.1f,
            /* yPrecision= */0.1f,
            /* deviceId= */mInputManager.getInputDevice(-1).id, //Using -1 as that's a virtual inputDevice
            /* edgeFalgs= */0,
            /* source= */InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD,
            /* flags= */0
        )
        mInputManager.injectInputEvent(event, InputEventInjectionSync.WAIT_FOR_RESULT)
        event.recycle()
```

Testing with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.elron.gamepadtester&hl=en_US&gl=US
For reference, this code works great acting like a left analog stick.

```
        val eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        val event = MotionEvent.obtain(
            /* downTime= */ eventTime,
            /* eventTime= */ eventTime,
            /* action= */ MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,
            /* x= */ angle,
            /* y= */ 0.0f,
            /* pressure= */ 1.0f,
            /* size= */ 0f,
            /* metaState= */ 0,
            /* xPrecision= */ 0.1f,
            /* yPrecision= */ 0.1f,
            /* deviceId= */ mInputManager.getInputDevice(-1).id,
            /* edgeFlags= */ 0
        )
        event.source = InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK
        mInputManager.injectInputEvent(event, InputEventInjectionSync.NONE)

        event.recycle()
```

I have tried different variants of InputEventInjectionSync, SOURCE_GAMEPAD, SOURCE_JOYSTICK, SOURCE_KEYBOARD and using different axis types in setAxisValue

Comment: Check the logcat, and try to find some useful log